# NSwagStudio how to generate enum properties as string

Tags: swagger, code-generation, swashbuckle, nswag, nswagstudio

I'd like to generate enum properties as string but when I use the `NSwagStudio` or `Unchase OpenApi` extension for VS2019 for generating C# client code, there is no specific property to do this.
In the properties file `ConnectedServices.json` there are these fields:

```
  "typeNameGeneratorType": null,
  "propertyNameGeneratorType": null,
  "enumNameGeneratorType": null,
```

As last chance I'd like to implement my custom `enumNameGeneratorType` but I cannot find any documentation on the web.

The `swagger.json` file contains this enum:

```
"status": {
  "type": "string",
  "description": "The status of the item",
  "example": "Open",
  "enum": [
    "Open"
  ]
}
```

Unless there is an automated way, I would not want to modify the swagger.json before importing it, as it is provided by a vendor. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: May I ask why you need enums to be strings? What is the goal here?

Comment: @AndrewSilver yes I'd need enums to be strings

Comment: @AndrewSilver Commonly it's because string represented enums are more semantic. It's largely the whole purpose of having an Enum instead of an int. They communicate more meaning for human maintainers.